# Ramdom 78 x 78 Pixels

Tags: php, html, random

I am trying to learn how to code and not to sure where to start,

I would like to produce a box that is 78 pixels by 78 pixels 
and then have them all a difrent random colour.

how would I do this on a html or php web page please ?

not realy sure where to start.

thanks for your help and time.

Comment: you can easily get the result you're looking for using JQuery and HTML + CSS

Comment: Please post the code that you already have.

Comment: When you say you're learning how to code, do you mean that you're learning how to program in general?  If so HTML/PHP is probably not the best place to start, if you're looking to make a career out of it.  C++, Java, Python, VB.Net, etc. are much better languages to start with.  And you don't want to start off doing much in the way of graphics either - maybe a button and a bit of text on the screen, at most.  But most tutorials and colleges and stuff will start you off with the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to approach such a problem, a simple one is using a table and [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) PHP function to set the [background](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) of each [cell](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_td.asp):

```
<?php
$size=78;
$cellsize=4;
$table="<table cellpadding='$cellsize' cellspacing='1'";
for($y=0;$y<$size;$y++) {
    $table.="<tr>";
    for($x=0;$x<$size;$x++) {
        // Random color
        $r=rand(0,255);
        $g=rand(0,255);
        $b=rand(0,255);
        $table.="<td style='background-color:rgb($r,$g,$b)'></td>";
    }
    $table.="</tr>\n";
}
$table.="</table>";

print $table;
?>
```

This code produces an HTML table. You can use other systems (for example [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)).

Comment: this works, fantastick thank you, i did not think about cells and tables, how would i make each cell hyper link to the home page, page1 or page2 ? looking at your code i am thinking 
 $stringlink=rand(0,3)
1= "herf:// \.home.html"
2= "herf:// \.page1.html"
3= "herf:// \.page2.html"
how would this fit into the above code please ?

Comment: Assuming you have a PHP array with the links (e.g. `$a_links=array("http://www.google.com","http://www.amazon.com","http://stackoverflow.com");`), in the inner cycle you can get your random url (`$url=$a_links[rand(0,2)];`). There are several ways to open the url by clicking on the cell. The simplest is adding an hyperlink in the cell `<td ...><a href='$url'>&nbsp;</a></td>`. Alternatively you can use some javascript (e.g. `<td ...  onclick='window.open(\"$url\");'></td>`). I suggest you to follow a programming manual and try to achieve your own solution.